# Quality analysis control doubts

Tags: c

I had run the quality analysis control for my code base and i have some doubts regarding some error value seen which is shown below:

this is just the code extract

```
typedef struct UISR_caller_info_s/*structure declaration*/
{
    unsigned char   number[20];    
    unsigned char   Name[30];
    unsigned int  numberType;                      
} caller_t;

static caller_t   gs_val;/*variable of the structure type*/
```

Error:

```
 2027:  strcpy((char *)gs_val.Name, NULL); 
                       ^
Msg(2:0310) Casting to different object pointer type. 
REFERENCE - ISO:C90-6.3.4 Cast Operators - Semantics <next>
```

The error is shown at the char * typecasting which i really have no idea why this is happening.
Please let me know how to avoid this kind of error

Thanks
GNR

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that `strcpy` call will likely cause a segmentation fault (and *definitely* causes undefined behaviour) - you probably don't want `NULL` for the second parameter.  You don't need the cast for your call anyway:

```
strcpy(gs_value.Name, "");
```

Will work fine, and is probably what you meant in the first place.  It may be that your compiler is *very* picky, and it's complaining about the cast from `unsigned char` to `char` - you can fix that by changing your structure appropriately.

Comment: @Carl...I had tried this ,but on running the QAC i found out the same error repeating

Comment: @carl...When i tried with (void *) typecast it worked fine.Not sure how it happenned

Comment: @Maddy - if you have `NULL` in your `strcpy` call it most definitely does *not* work fine.